# Is there any chance that CLOCK_REALTIME changes time automatically?

Tags: c++, linux, datetime, system, system-calls

I'm using linux api clock_gettime(realtime) to print current time. Check log index ending with 649 and 917.

The real clock time was 1646948676.999081502(at index 649)
,but after 10 secs it suddenly jumped more than >24 hours back and was 1646860487.614595043(index 917).

Main thing i wanna know is what is VuC offset? Will VucOffset affect this realtime?
and

Could you please explain what is the reason for time jump? and how can we avoid this?

```
221649 2022/03/10 02:44:37.000000 PF_CLOCK_SYNC CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW=35.228995663 s CLOCK_MONOTONIC=35.228996808 s CLOCK_REALTIME=1646948676.999081502 s
230583 2022/03/10 02:44:46.000000 receiveTMPData data received !!
230584 2022/03/10 02:44:46.000000 TMP::Data received is: -56563019
230585 2022/03/10 02:44:46.000000 TMP:TM_OUTPUT_VUC_OFFSET IS SET!!
231917 2022/03/10 02:44:47.000000 PF_CLOCK_SYNC CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW=45.230177586 s CLOCK_MONOTONIC=45.230296214 s CLOCK_REALTIME=1646860487.614595043 s
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And if you have problem with behavior of your code (which this probably is) then a [mre] of your program would be very good to have.

Comment: What is the code that prints the time? I didn't find mention of any offset in the documentation: https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

Comment: What is `VucOffset`? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @VLL clockgettime returns and stores the time in nanosecs format.
for example clockgettime(realtime, varname) stores time in varname.

Comment: @VLL clock_gettime does not print the output that is shown in your question. It does not print anything. Where is the code that prints the output? Your question is "what is VuC offset", but that is something you calculate in your own code. How is the "VuC offset" calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CLOCK_REALTIME` is your classic "wall clock", similar in spirit to what is returned by the older [gettimeofday()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) function call.  In particular, it is non-monotonic, which means that it can be expected under some circumstances to 'jump' forward or backwards by an arbitrary amount.

Generally "some circumstances" will be limited to "immediately after the local user calls [settimeofday()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/settimeofday) or by some other mechanism changes his computer's clock setting"; but it is also possible for an automated clock-synchronization (like ntpd or ptpd) to automatically adjust the clock forwards or backwards if it feels the need to do so.  (I wouldn't expect either of those to adjust the clock by 24 hours unless they decided that the computer's existing clock-value was 24 hours off from the clock they are trying to synchronize it to, of course).